# Como listar containers no Docker?

Tags: bash, docker

Recentemente comecei a fazer testes no Docker, criei uma maquina virtual e instalei o Debian 9 sem interface gráfica. Sei que o comando:

```
docker ps
```

Mostra os recipientes em execução, existe outros comandos em que eu possa pesquisar se um determinado recipiente foi criado ?

Pois terei a necessidade de executar um *Shell Script* para verificar se o recipiente existe e se esta em execução.

Exemplo:

```
$ sudo docker ps | grep 'recipiente-nome'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
CONTAINER_NAME='mycontainername'

CID=$(docker ps -q -f status=running -f name=^/${CONTAINER_NAME}$)
if [ ! "${CID}" ]; then
  echo "Container doesn't exist"
fi
unset CID
```

ou

```
if [ ! "$(docker ps -q -f name=<name>)" ]; then
    if [ "$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=<name>)" ]; then
        # cleanup
        docker rm <name>
    fi
    # run your container
    docker run -d --name <name> my-docker-image
fi
```

Para referência:

> **docker ps [OPTIONS]**
>
> **Options**
>
> --all , -a        Show all containers (default shows just running)
>
> --filter , -f     Filter output based on conditions provided
>
> --format      Pretty-print containers using a Go template
>
> --last , -n   -1  Show n last created containers (includes all states)
>
> --latest , -l     Show the latest created container (includes all states)
>
> --no-trunc        Don’t truncate output
>
> --quiet , -q      Only display numeric IDs
>
> --size , -s       Display total file sizes

Comment: Muito bem, você poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/270914/edit) sua resposta e explicar o parâmetro `-a`? Para futura referência.

Comment: Tá feito meu amigo, um abraço

Comment: A condição não esta funcionando ! Esta retornando `not found`

Comment: @wmsouza editei a resposta e coloquei mais alternativas, se puder testar abs.